# Can't set correct background color for UITextField in UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I use UISearchController im my project like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7caxpp3Xps
And I try to set textField background like in answer here:
[iOS 11 customise search bar in navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007260/ios-11-customise-search-bar-in-navigation-bar)
If I use colors like blue, green, white, black  all ok
But when I try to set another color I got result like

[image]

Also I have two _UISearchBarSearchFieldBackgroundView inside UISearchBarTextField and one of them is filled by another color 
[image]

is it a bug of apple developers?

Code of viewController -  [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/marinat/101c073258004d6ea524ae0c7bf0dd56)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805553/extension-for-uicolor-with-custom-colors-it-is-real use this

Comment: thats not work for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814179/how-to-change-uitextfield-color-in-searchcontroller try this if again not working then tell

Answer (score 0):

Create class property in UIColor extension

```
extension UIColor
{
  class var themeColor:UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 210.0/255.0, green: 105.0/255.0, blue: 130.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
  }
}
OR

extension UIColor {
  static let themeColor = UIColor(red: 210.0/255.0, green: 105.0/255.0, blue: 130.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
Usage

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.themeColor
```

original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805553/extension-for-uicolor-with-custom-colors-it-is-real)

Comment: No, same result again

Comment: searchController.searchBar.isTranslucent = false, but same =(

Comment: make sure you use the right color representation if so i know it sounds stupid to check but just double check, i had similar problem in the past and this pretty much solved i am running out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can set tint color and background color of searchBar.

`controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.appThemeColor()` `controller.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`

```
controller.searchBar.tintColor = Color.theme.value
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code to customize other things also if you want**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchBar.customize()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension UISearchBar {
    func customize(){
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.backgroundImage = UIImage()

        for subView in self.subviews  {
            for subsubView in subView.subviews  {
                if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField {
                    textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
                    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                    textField.layer.cornerRadius = textField.bounds.size.height / 2
                    textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
                    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                }
            }
        }

        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "searchfield")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UISearchBarIcon.search, state: .normal)
        self.setPositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0), for: UISearchBarIcon.search)
        self.searchTextPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 8, vertical: 0)
    }
}
```